# validate.js to validate field

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
var v = $("#form1").validate({
    ignore: ':hidden',
    rules: {
        rdbMenuItem: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        rdbMenuItem: "*",
        review: "*"
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="rdb1" type="radio" value="0" name="rdbMenuItem">
<input id="rdb2" type="radio" value="3" name="rdbMenuItem">
<input id="rdb3" type="radio" value="2" name="rdbMenuItem">
<input id="rdb4" type="radio" value="1" name="rdbMenuItem">
```

And in a click event:

```
$('#imgAdd').live("click", function() {
    if (v.form()) {    
        Alert("s");
        MenuMgr.LoadMenu();
    }
    else {
        Alert("f");
        return;
    }
});
```

But this always fires  `alert("s")` no matter whether a radio button is checked or not. I don't understand what the problem is. Please help to find my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: validate.js handles form submit, so you need to submit your form in imgAdd click. also not that it will only fire if data is valid, so no need to check for validity again.

Comment: @www.DotNetNukeLab.com if its true then why shouldn't show validation message `*`.Thanks for reply.

Comment: what I would suggest is to try:  
$('#imgAdd').live("click", function() { $('#form1').trigger('submit'); });